# Difference between MOSFET cascode and MOSFET in series

Tags: mosfet, cascode

When using two MOSFETs in the cascode configuration the output resistance is approximated as gm × ro1 × ro2 where gm is the transconductance of the top device, ro1 the drain source resistance of the top device and ro2 is the drain source resistance of the bottom device. This increases the output resistance of the combination.

However MOSFETs are also used in series while holding Vgs of both the same  so that effectively the channel length is doubled and the current in the combination is halved. This would be similar to saying that the output resistance has doubled.

I'm not able to understand this. Does the output resistance increase by a factor of 2 or ro2?

Please help.

Comment: Surely the assumption that the current is halved is not true if the device is in saturation. The two devices have different Vgs voltages.

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges, in a cascode circuit, the "bottom" MOSFET is kept in saturation mode (by applying the correct gate voltage to the cascode transistor). With two MOSFETs in series, that is not the case. With two MOSFETs in series both get **the same** gate voltage so such a combined MOSFET behaves **exactly the same** as one MOSFET with a longer channel length (and then \$r_o\$ is only doubled)